# Converting an object into numbers

Tags: javascript, html

Hello again stack overflow! Another day another rookie question.
I have been trying to create my own simple little calculator and so far I have been working on the add function.
It is working without errors but its adding values as if they were strings.
I have been trying to place Numbers() and parseInt() around different variables to try and make them into numbers so the addition will work, but so far no matter what I do they wont change from an Object.
(I found this out with console.log(typeof variable)

Here is my code!

```
var input = document.querySelector(".input");
let previousInput = null;

function add(){     
    if(previousInput === null){
        document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML += input.value
        previousInput = input;
    } else {
      document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = previousInput.value + input.value
      console.log(typeof input)
      console.log(typeof previousInput)
    }
}
```

---

```
    <input class="input" type="text"></div>
    <button type="button" onClick="add();">+</button>
    <div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: if u have the time to downvote, then please explain why this is wrongly phrased so i can rephrase it and do it better next time.
console shows objects. i  need to change the objects into numbers to do the math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var input = document.querySelector(".input");
let previousInput = null;

function add(){     
    if(previousInput === null){
        document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML += input.value
        previousInput = parseInt(input.value);
    } else {
       document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = previousInput + parseInt(input.value)
       previousInput += parseInt(input.value);
    }
}
```

I added some parseInt() to actually evaluate the values to int.

**Warning**: your previous code would just be able to add once the values and wouldn't work after that you need to raise the value of previousInput as well after updating the .ouput element

Comment: thanks :)! yeah that was the next part i was gonna do. but had the issue with objects and couldnt convert them into numbers or make them operate as numbers! thanks for the heads up neways !:) +rep

Answer (score 1):

You have put `previousInput = input`, here, input is the `#input` selector, not storing the value.

You need to store `number` on `previousInput` as follows.

```js
var input = document.querySelector(".input");
let previousInput = null;

function add() {
  if(previousInput === null){
    document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = input.value;
    previousInput = parseInt(input.value);
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = previousInput + parseInt(input.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text"></div>
<button type="button" onClick="add();">+</button>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this,  I tried to use parseInt and it seems to work in codepen. Check here:
https://codepen.io/upretim/pen/oNxKWjY

```
var input = document.querySelector(".input");
let previousInput = null;

    function add(){     
        if(previousInput === null){
            document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML += input.value
            previousInput = input;
        } else {
          document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = parseInt(previousInput.value) + parseInt(input.value)
          console.log(typeof input)
          console.log(typeof previousInput)
        }
    }
```